# Let $S$ be any infinite set. Is it true that $S \times \mathbb{Z}$ has the same cardinality as $S$?

Tags: set-theory

Consider any set $S$ which is not finite. Is it true that $S \times \mathbb{Z}$ has the same cardinality as $S$?

I thought the answer is "yes" and I thought it would be a trivial problem. But as I think about it, I have a nagging feeling it requires something like the Axiom of Choice and now, I'm not even sure the answer is "yes."

One cursory idea I had was to consider an injection of $\{s\} \times \mathbb{Z} \to S$ for each fixed $s \in S$. Somehow, if we can patch these together to form another injection $S \times \mathbb{Z}$, we would be done.

Comment: Well, depending on your understanding of cardinal arithmetic, we know that $$|A \times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$$ which is $\max\{|A|,|B|\}$ for infinite $A$ or $B$ and both non-empty. This does assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Randall $S$ needn't be countable.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer I see; I wasn't aware of this fact. Thanks!

Comment: @inkievoyd woah,I totally missed that.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of the question that was linked in the closure. Instead [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896440/) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915791/) provide proofs of $|S\times \Bbb Z|=|S|$.